# Imagemagick 7.0.8-59 Error Message when Compressing PDF files

Tags: bash, pdf, compression, imagemagick, ghostscript

I am trying to compress a PDF with this Command: mogrify -compress jpeg -quality 50 path/to/file/*

When running the Command I get this error message:

```
Error: ICCbased space /N value does not match the ICC profile.
Using the number of channels from the profile.
Output may be incorrect.
libpng warning: Image width is zero in IHDR
libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
libpng error: Invalid IHDR data
Error: /VMerror in --showpage--
VM status: 3 7801272 9177632
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
GPL Ghostscript 9.27: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Does anybody know what the Origin of this error is ?

*(I already Cleaned and updated Homebrew, Imagemagick, gs) (Running on a Mac machine 10.13.6)*

Comment: Also getting this - did you find a solution / yet? :\

Comment: Also getting this on latest Ubuntu release, using `gs -sDevice=pdfwrite` for any file. This used to work fine, for years.

Comment: @jtlz2 No I have not found a solution yet.